# Mysql Database Isn't Updating

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

Okay so users on my game have a page. Other users can comment on the page. I made a script to where the user can set it to where people can comment on their wall or if it's disabled. If I manually change the database it works, but I have it setup with radio buttons and it's not updating. Here's the form.

```
<form action="settings" method="post">
Comments: <br />
Enabled:  
<input type="radio" name="change_wall" id="change_wall" value="no" checked="checked" />
<br />
Disabled: 
<input type="radio" name="change_wall" id="change_wall" value="yes" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>
```

Below this is the SQL of the database updating.

```
    <?php
    if ( isset ( $_POST['change_wall'] ) )
        {
        $change_wall = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['change_wall']); 
        if ($cash >= 5000) {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET disable_wall='".$change_wall."' , cash=(cash - 5000) WHERE id='".$id."'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
            echo  
            '<table width="800" align="center" class="SettingsTable">
              <tr>
                <td>You sucessfully changed your comment settings!</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br />';
        }
        else  {
            echo 
            '<table width="800" align="center" class="SettingsTable">
              <tr>
                <td>You don\'t have enough cash to change your comment settings!</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br />'; 
        }
        }
?>
```

Here's the coding for the user's page to display their comments or if it's disabled.

```
  <?php 
      if ($disable_wall = 0) { 
        include 'users_wall.php';
      }
      elseif ($disable_wall = 1) {
          echo 
          '<table width="800" align="center" class="DisabledWall">
          <tr>
            <td>' . $userp['name'] . '\'s ' . 'Comments Disabled!</td>
          </tr>
        </table>';
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is $id? I dont think you are passing the id through the form

Comment: @MAXIM All variables are passed through. In the header.php it identifies all variables.

Comment: try changing it to GET method just to see in the url what is being passed

Comment: @maxim - or print_r($_POST) ... user189xxx have you tried mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())

Comment: It gave me the url. http://psychowars.com/psychowars/settings?change_wall=0

Comment: Also, you sure the user in question has more or equal to 5000 cash? by the way, you don't need the parenthesis for cash - 5000 or the space before the comma after '".$change_wall."'

Comment: btw, it goes to settings? couldnt it be a typo? or settings.php?

Comment: I just updated the question. read it and it now shows the full script

Comment: I have the .htaccess file to not put .php

Comment: Well, could this work then?
if ($change_wall = 0) {
$sql = "UPDATE users SET disable_wall='0' , cash=(cash - 5000);
elseif ($change_wall = 1) {
$sql = "UPDATE users SET disable_wall='1' , cash=(cash - 5000);

Comment: @user see dimaninc's answer. He identified your problem as the incorrect database datatype. If you change the db structure for the cash field to int it will clear your problem, so long as you only have integers in that column.

Comment: Well, i changed disable_wall to an int and nothing changed.

Comment: what does mysql_error() result in?

Comment: When i did .. <?php echo mysql_error(); ?>
it echoed nothing. So I don't believe their's an error.

Comment: Also, if you print_r($sql) before your query, then copy and paste the string it prints out and try to run it in phpmyadmin directly, what error do you get

Comment: Well, when I did the print_r($sql) it printed the SQL line from my header file? Not the SQL line of the current script?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"UPDATE users SET disable_wall='".$change_wall."' , cash=(cash - 5000) WHERE id=' at line 1
 
.. that's the error I get when I paste into SQL

Comment: You put print_r($sql) right under this line, right: $sql = "UPDATE users SET disable_wall='".$change_wall."' , cash=(cash - 5000) WHERE id='".$id."'";

Comment: Alright, let me put it under their

Comment: Okay, it echoed: UPDATE users SET disable_wall='0' , cash=(cash - 5000) WHERE id='1' and when I put it into SQL their was no error. 1 row affected. ( Query took 0.0007 sec )

Comment: ok then right BEFORE this line: if ($cash >= 5000) { do print_r($cash) to make sure cash is actually >= 5000 it shouldnt matter if cash is an int or string in this case. PHP will interpret it correctly either way.

Comment: Well, in the header your cash is shown. 
xX BAD KARMA Xx | Level: 100 Logout
Cash: $120,000
Bank: $30,000
etc.

Comment: That doesn't mean $cash is still what you're expecting. Since we can't see your code, we can safely assume it is possible $cash is being redefined to $120,000 in which case your conditional would return false and nothing would run

Comment: Thank you all for the help and time you spent helping. I feel like an idiot, Lol. It wasn't the SQL that was messing up. in the header file I had the variable defined wrong. 
it was:
$disable_wall = $stats['disable_walls'];
    It was suppose to be :    
$disable_wall = $stats['disable_wall'];

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not looking earlier

Answer (score 1):

first of all, be sure that the sql query is executed - $cash is really >= 5000 and $id variable consists proper value

then, what type does the table field 'disable_wall' have? varchar or enum? not int?

if instructions above didnt help, type this after last line of your script:

```
die("error: ".mysql_error());
```

submit the form and watch, what error happened while you are updating the table

Comment: disable_wall is a varchar. I changed it back to where 0 = commented enabled and 1 is where the comments are disabled. It works if i manually change the value in database, but it won't update automatically

Comment: varchar is the problem then. The DB field should be int or any other numerical datatype.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. I have cash set as a varchar and it's updated all the time.

Comment: You're right, the varchar will add to itself if there is not a string present before the update. In that case it will only overwrite the previous value

Comment: @user you are. Yeah it will update, but with unexpected results if there is a string present. Like $1000. In that case it will overwrite the string with the increment amount. If there is an int before a string identifier, it will increment before string. so 500_50 would result in 5500 for cash = cash + 5000.

Comment: So would be it best if I changed cash to an INT? The way I have it setup to display for each user is like this. <?php echo number_format($cash) ?>

Comment: structurally, it is always best to use the right datatype for the data. In this case, cash should only ever be an int if whole numbers. If not, it should be decimal or numeric. PHP may be able to interpret a string with number_format, but it is good form to be somewhat proper in that respect. I would use int(11) unless you can have a number like 100.55 in which case a decimal would be fine

Comment: Well, cash won't have decimal, so I'll make it an INT(11)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need a boolean (yes/no) response, you can simply set them to 0 or 1, to be safe. 
To answer your question, do

```
 
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET disable_wall='1' , cash=(cash - 5000);
```

And to disable the wall

```
 
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET disable_wall='0' , cash=(cash - 5000);
```

Better yet, use a boolean column for it.

Also, ensure that **$id** is a valid value, and currently has at least a row in the table.

More importantly, use PDO or MySQLi; MySQL extensions are already deprecated.

 
Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean "radio and check buttons do not provide values" they both do if they're checked. if they are not, they do not have values. In his case there will always be one passed since he defines yes and no and provides a default checked.

Comment: Well I have done a register with radio buttons before to check and see if the user was a male or female and it worked. So what's the difference from it working with INSERT and not UPDATE?

Comment: If a radio/check button isn't checked, the name won't appear in POST; if it is checked, the name will appear, but whatever value you assigned it won't;

Comment: Absolutely incorrect, sir. change the value of change_wall to "rofl" and echo $_POST['change_wall'] will print out rofl

Comment: That has been my experience, but I'll certainly try it, and if it works fine, I'll let you know.

Comment: @KaiQing; my apologies for the mistake; you are certainly correct; I have modified my answer to reflect the change. Thanks for the information.